# DetailsView ObjectDataSource OnUpdate Cannot Convert from String to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, webforms, objectdatasource, detailsview

`DetailsView` on edit mode can't convert readonly `DateTime` field to `String`
I solved the problem, but it didn't seem to me the most elegant way of solving it.
Why does it happen?

**DetailsView on edit mode**
[image: DetailsView]

**Exception after click on 'Update'**
[image: Exception]

**ASPX**

```xml
<asp:DetailsView
    ID="PersonDetails" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="PersonSource"
    ItemType="SubjectD.Models.HbPerson"
    AllowPaging="false"
    AutoGenerateRows="false"
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
    AutoGenerateInsertButton="true">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="Id" SortExpression="Id" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NameFirst" DataField="NameFirst" SortExpression="NameFirst" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NameMiddle" DataField="NameMiddle" SortExpression="NameMiddle" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NameLast" DataField="NameLast" SortExpression="NameLast" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SocialNumber" DataField="SocialNumber" SortExpression="SocialNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Created" DataField="Created" SortExpression="Created" 
            ReadOnly="true" /> <!-- DateTime -->
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Modified" DataField="Modified" SortExpression="Modified" 
            ReadOnly="true" /> <!-- DateTime -->
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource
    ID="PersonSource" runat="server"
    TypeName="SubjectD.Business.BizPerson"
    DataObjectTypeName="SubjectD.Models.HbPerson"
    EnablePaging="true"
    MaximumRowsParameterName="maxRows"
    StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex"
    SortParameterName="sortExpression"
    SelectCountMethod="Count"
    SelectMethod="SelectPerson"
    UpdateMethod="Update">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" DefaultValue="0" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**What I did to resolve it**

I handled the `OnItemUpdating` event on `DetailsView`

```xml
<asp:DetailsView
    ...
    OnItemUpdating="PersonDetails_ItemUpdating">
</asp:DetailsView>
```

And did this:

```cs
protected void PersonDetails_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    var modified = e.OldValues[5];
    e.NewValues.Add("Modified", modified);
}
```

Now the exception does not occur.
Is this the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does your code work currently (it seems to, based on what you said)?  Do you have an issue where your code is not working?  If the answer to the first question is "yes" and the second "no", then Stack Overflow is probably not the right QA site for this question.  Try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes and Yes.
I'd like to know why the exception occurred.
It seemed to me that I forgot to set something up, so someone who understands a lot of it could explain why only one field (there are two DateTime fields marked as read only) could not convert DateTime to String.